# OpenOffice 3.3 Breaks My Code

Tags: vba, openoffice.org

I cannot use `Cells(x,y)` anymore in OpenOffice (seems to be a bug, from what I can gather googling `Cells.select`). Are there any workaround for this (with different code)? I need to respond to the value returned from `Cells(x,y)` of course.

The error is:

```
unsatisfied query of type ooo.vba.excel.XWorksheet!
```

Comment: Have you tried converting that to a Range() reference, or maybe Columns(y).Cells(x) or Rows(x).Cells(y) ?

Comment: A little googling never hurts:   http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Cells_and_Ranges

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams that helps. I put an answer together from what I found there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either everything changed for 3.3, or they just broke everything by accident. The most likely case is that everything I was using has been deprecated, but it might be temporarily broken.

In any case, you can no longer use the naked `Cells(y,x)`. Now you have to use

```
    Sheet =  ThisComponent.getCurrentController.getActiveSheet
    Cell = Sheet.getCellByPosition(x, y)
```

Note:

1. The docs are [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Editing_Spreadsheet_Documents) (thanks to @Tim Williams for Google support).
2. Unlike with cells, the x and y are now "normal" (column, row), not inverted. Also, the index is zero-based.
3. To select a cell you have to use

   ```
   ThisComponent.getCurrentController().createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper").select(cell)
   ```
4. To get the active cell

   ```
   oCell = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()
   If not oCell.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCell") Then
     return
   End If
   ' do stuff here
   ```